# Getting Beacon Fence Using Awareness API it's take too much time and not accurate

Tags: java, android, google-awareness

*This is my code for getting BeaconFence.It's take too much time and not  provide accurate information i fetch two fence lost and found*

//BeaconFenceActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.azilen.awarenessapidemo.R;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.Awareness;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.fence.AwarenessFence;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.fence.BeaconFence;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.fence.FenceState;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.fence.FenceUpdateRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.awareness.state.BeaconState;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BeaconFenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 940;
    private TextView txtBeacon;


    private static final String BEACON_FENCE_KEY = "BEACON_FENCE_KEY";
    private static final int BEACON_ZONE_IN = 2;
    private static final int BEACON_ZONE_OUT = 1;

    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private BeaconFenceReceiver mBeaconFenceReceiver;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    //Replace this with app's Google project name
    private static final List<BeaconState.TypeFilter> BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS = Arrays.asList
            (BeaconState.TypeFilter.with("awarenessapidemo-158205", "beacondemo"));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon_fence);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(BeaconFenceActivity.this);
        mProgress.setTitle("Geting Near Beacon");
        mProgress.setMessage("Please wait..");

        txtBeacon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fence_beacon);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(BeaconFenceActivity.this).addApi(Awareness.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        mBeaconFenceReceiver = new BeaconFenceReceiver();
        Intent intent = new Intent(BeaconFenceReceiver.BEACON_FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION);
        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BeaconFenceActivity.this, 1, intent, 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getBeaconDetails();
        registerReceiver(mBeaconFenceReceiver, new IntentFilter(BeaconFenceReceiver.BEACON_FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterFences();
        unregisterReceiver(mBeaconFenceReceiver);
    }


    private void getBeaconDetails() {
        mProgress.show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            mProgress.hide();
        } else {
            AwarenessFence beaconFoundFence = BeaconFence.found(BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS);
            AwarenessFence lostFence = BeaconFence.lost(BEACON_TYPE_FILTERS);
            AwarenessFence orFence = AwarenessFence.or(lostFence, beaconFoundFence);

            Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(mGoogleApiClient,
                    new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                            .addFence(BEACON_FENCE_KEY, orFence, mPendingIntent)
                         /* .addFence(BEACON_FENCE_KEY, beaconFoundFence, mPendingIntent)
                            .addFence(BEACON_FENCE_KEY, lostFence, mPendingIntent)
                           */
                            .build()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "Fence Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "Fence Not Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            mProgress.hide();
        }
    }

    private void unregisterFences() {
        Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                        .removeFence(BEACON_FENCE_KEY)
                        .build()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallbacks<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(@NonNull Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "Fence Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "Fence Not Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void checkRestart(View view) {
        getBeaconDetails();
        registerReceiver(mBeaconFenceReceiver, new IntentFilter(BeaconFenceReceiver.BEACON_FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION));
    }

    public class BeaconFenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static final String BEACON_FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION = "com.azilen.awarenessapidemo.activities.fence.BeaconFenceReceiver.BEACON_FENCE_RECEIVER_ACTION";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Recived", "Received a Beacon Fence Broadcast");
            FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);
            Log.e("FenceState Status:-", String.valueOf(fenceState.getFenceKey()));
            if (TextUtils.equals(fenceState.getFenceKey(), BEACON_FENCE_KEY)) {
                Log.e("FenceState:-", String.valueOf(fenceState.getCurrentState()));
                switch (fenceState.getCurrentState()) {
                    case FenceState.TRUE: {
                        setBeaconState(BEACON_ZONE_IN);
                        Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "You've entered the beacon zone!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Beacon", "In Range");
                        break;
                    }
                    case FenceState.FALSE: {
                        setBeaconState(BEACON_ZONE_OUT);
                        Log.e("Beacon", "Out of Range");
                        Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "You've Out of beacon Range!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    case FenceState.UNKNOWN: {
                        setBeaconState(FenceState.UNKNOWN);
                        Log.e("Beacon", "UNKNOWN");
                        Toast.makeText(BeaconFenceActivity.this, "Oops, Beacon status is unknown!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }

    private void setBeaconState(int beaconState) {
        if (beaconState == BEACON_ZONE_IN) {
            txtBeacon.setText("You've entered the beacon zone!");
        } else if (beaconState == BEACON_ZONE_OUT) {
            txtBeacon.setText("You're not in the beacon zone..");
        } else {
            txtBeacon.setText("Oops, Beacon status is unknown!");
        }
    }
}
```

I Hope you can understand my question.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it is taking to much time.
But in case of the accuracy you have to keep in mind,
that your position to the beacons is calculated from
the signal/signalstrength that beacons send and like every signal in 
the microwave spectrum it gets reflected, blocked etc.
The environment in which you use your beacons could be
far from ideal to get the accuracy you want with the information
provided by the beacons.